# How to avoid OpenMP clause `reduction`?

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

In a loop, a subroutine `mySub` that calculates a matrix `myThreadMatrix` is called. The result is summed in `mySumMatrix` that has a clause `REDUCTION`

```
program main

    use omp_lib
    implicit none

    integer :: ii
    integer, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: mySumMatrix, myThreadMatrix
    
    ! test on 4 threads (only for this short example, not real life)
    call OMP_set_dynamic(.FALSE.)
    call OMP_set_num_threads(4)
    
    allocate(mySumMatrix(1:3,1:3), myThreadMatrix(1:3,1:3))
    mySumMatrix(1:3,1:3)=0
    
    !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(myThreadMatrix) REDUCTION(+:mySumMatrix)
        myThreadMatrix(1:3,1:3)=0
        !$OMP DO
        do ii=1,10
            call mySub(myThreadMatrix)
            mySumMatrix=mySumMatrix+myThreadMatrix
        enddo
        !$OMP END DO
    !$OMP END PARALLEL

    print *, mySumMatrix
    
contains

    subroutine mySub(myMatrix)
    
        integer, dimension(1:3,1:3), intent(out) :: myMatrix
    
        ! doing some long calculations ....
        myMatrix(1:3,1:3)=omp_get_thread_num()+1
    
        return
        
    end subroutine mySub
    
end program main
```

It works fine but, in my real program, `mySumMatrix` is big. So, I would like to avoid to duplicate it in each thread. So I wonder how to avoid the use of `REDUCTION` clause.
After many tries, I managed to do that with this program :

```
program main

    use omp_lib
    implicit none

    integer :: ii
    integer, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: mySumMatrix, myThreadMatrix
    
    ! test on 4 threads (only for this short example, not real life)
    call OMP_set_dynamic(.FALSE.)
    call OMP_set_num_threads(4)
    
    allocate(mySumMatrix(1:3,1:3), myThreadMatrix(1:3,1:3))
    mySumMatrix(1:3,1:3)=0
       
    !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(myThreadMatrix) SHARED(mySumMatrix)
        myThreadMatrix(1:3,1:3)=0
        !$OMP DO
        do ii=1,10
            call mySub(myThreadMatrix)
        enddo
        !$OMP END DO
        !$OMP DO ORDERED
        do ii=1,omp_get_num_threads()
            !$OMP ORDERED
            mySumMatrix=mySumMatrix+myThreadMatrix
            !$OMP END ORDERED
        enddo
        !$OMP END DO
    !$OMP END PARALLEL

    print *,mySumMatrix

contains

    subroutine mySub(myMatrix)
    
        integer, dimension(1:3,1:3), intent(out) :: myMatrix
    
        ! doing some long calculations ....
        myMatrix(1:3,1:3)=myMatrix(1:3,1:3)+omp_get_thread_num()+1
    
        return
        
    end subroutine mySub
    
end program main
```

But, as I am a beginner in parallel programming and OpenMP, I am not sure that this solution does not have problems that I do not suspect. May I have some advice ?
Thanks a lot for answer.

Comment: Reductions are usually good. Ordered is usually bad. If you cannot make private copies of the whole matrix, work on smaller manageable tiles.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава. Why reductions are good and ordered is bad ?

Comment: I read in different posts that there are some problems with reduction and allocatable arrays. Is it still on ?

Comment: Reductions allow running the computations at full power. Ordered slows the computation down. I am not aware of any problems with allocatable arrays. You can make your tiles fixed-size though.

Comment: `ordered` restricts the scheduling of the operations so it makes the execution harder to parallelize. `ordered` is a mess for OpenMP implementations as it makes them much more complex (so much that runtime developers wanted this feature to be removed but it is sometime very useful for OpenMP users). In the end, it is not rare that runtimes implement this feature inefficiently for maintainability purposes (making it less useful for users). It is sometimes faster to emulate this feature with tasks and data dependencies.

Comment: @JérômeRichard. Thanks for answer. It is funny but I called my file that use `ordered` : *big_mess* as you wrote. Do you have a document to advise me on "Good and Bad practises in parallel programming" ?

Comment: @Stef1611 I think books or lectures on parallel programmings should do the job (especially ones talking about OpenMP). I personally learned a lot about this in research papers, conferences and by writing many parallel programs during my thesis on the subject, but this is certainly not the fastest solution ;) . This is a pretty broad domain. You can start by reading the [introduction book of Victor Eijkhout](https://web.corral.tacc.utexas.edu/CompEdu/pdf/stc/EijkhoutIntroToHPC.pdf). Then check for the documentation section of OpenMP: I think there should be books talking about this.

Comment: @JérômeRichard. PierU suggested me to use OMP CRITICAL. I wonder if CRITICAL as the same problem than ORDERED ?

Comment: @Stef1611 Critical can be completely no-go slow or quite reasonable, depending on where the time is actually spent. How much time does the call to `mySub` take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by just inserting a CRITICAL directive in your original code (and of course keeping the SHARED instead of REDUCTION) :

```
!$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(myThreadMatrix) SHARED(mySumMatrix)
        myThreadMatrix(1:3,1:3)=0
        !$OMP DO
        do ii=1,10
            call mySub(myThreadMatrix)
            !$OMP CRITICAL
                mySumMatrix=mySumMatrix+myThreadMatrix
            !$OMP END CRITICAL
        enddo
        !$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

CRITICAL ensures that only one thread at a time executes the code inside the critical section, so here that only one thread at a time updates mySumMatrix. CRITICAL has some performance penalty, but which can be perfectly acceptable if the time spent within the critical section is small compared to the time spent within the whole parallel section. In your case, if the computations made in mySub() are much more important than the matrix summation you won't even notice the penalty (and by the way, if they are not much more important then the whole OMP parallelism is probably pointless).

Besides, I think your modified code with ORDERED is not valid, and if it is I doubt it can give the right result.

Comment: What is the best thing to do : CRITICAL or REDUCTION ? Is OMP CRITICAL *bad* like ORDERED (see comments) ?

Comment: @Stef1611 There is not a "best thing to do" here, CRITICAL or REDUCTION have both advantages and drawbacks. In your case the REDUCTION solution requires more memory (and this is why you were initially searching for alternatives), and the CRITICAL solution may have some performance penalty.

Also, CRITICAL or ORDERED aren't necessarily _bad_: yes they result in some performance penalty, but if they are used carefully the penalty can be small or even unnoticeable.